# injecting external js into self created iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

So i am trying to inject and external css and js into a self created iframe to provide an extra security layer, there therefore is no cross domain issues.

here is the code

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script>
$(function(){

var contents = $('iframe').contents();

styleTag = $('<link href="http://mylink.com/styles.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />').appendTo(contents.find('head'));

insertScript('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js');
insertScript('https://myserver.com/myfile.js');

});

var insertScript = function(src){
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = src;
$('iframe').contents().find('head').append(script);
console.log("add script");
}

</script>

<div class="output">
<iframe></iframe>
</div>
```

the css file is being inputted but neither of the js files are, can anyone see why? the console.log is outputting.

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>I think you have to create the script element from the iframe's document object. It should be available as `contents[0]`, which you can pass to insertScript.</strike>

It works if you use `appendChild` directly on your head node (not the jQuery wrapper):

```
$('iframe').contents().find('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

http://jsbin.com/enidiv/1/edit

Comment: hmm, i am a bit confused? could you provide me with an example?

Comment: Actually, that was wrong. But I believe I found something that works, see the updated answer.

Comment: good man! dont know why someone marked the question down in the first place but appreciate the help

Comment: I have made a edit http://jsbin.com/enidiv/2/edit (http://jsbin.com/enidiv/2) and i get a $ error. it seems to think jquery isnt there?

Comment: @Dan When you insert scripts to the DOM dynamically, like you're doing in the iframe, they are loaded asynchronously. So you'll have to add an onload event handler to the jquery script, and only load dependencies when it finished loading. The same is true for any other dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the iframe domain, protocol, and port matches you can add scripts. Otherwise, it is treated as an unsafe attempt to access a different url.

Comment: but this is all in the same page as can be seen in the example.. so it has to be same domain but adds the css but not the js