# External .css and .js in iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, browser

There is a server, which serves web page (let's call it host web server). This page contains `iframe`, which connects to my device and displays the content delivered by its HTTP server. It is a small device with low-bandwidth connection, so I need to decrease the data transfer size. Still I want my web page to look nice, be responsive etc., so I would like to load Bootstrap and Angular from some external location. But there is a limitation for the web browser - it cannot load external resources inside the `iframe`.

All the solutions I've found assumed editing access to the outer web page. It is not possible for me, because it is some other company's service.

Is there any solution for this problem?

**EDIT:**
I would expect first to UNDERSTAND the question before down-voting and provide a reason for that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [from iframe page event change css of parent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19537555/from-iframe-page-event-change-css-of-parent) (If your iframe and parent contents aren't in the same domain, you're out of luck and will be blocked by CORS.)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. You will need JavaScript to achieve what you want. 
`myiframe.$('div').style.border = '1px solid #000000'`

would be a good start.

As for injecting your own JS, Stack has a good answer here:
[injecting external js into self created iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16051076/injecting-external-js-into-self-created-iframe)

Comment: The problem is that I am INSIDE the frame (which displays content from different domain) so I cannot load any external script (i.e. jquery, which is needed for your code to work). I cannot even access the `document` element and its children, so I cannot execute append(script).