# How To Invoke External Javascript file in Iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Let's suppose I'm adding Iframes to a site. Now in the HTML of that site I have an external javascipt file that I want only to be executed in iframes. How can I do that? Is it possible?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Is this similiar to what you are trying to achieve by any chance? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16051076/injecting-external-js-into-self-created-iframe

Comment: If you **do not** control, own, or have administrative access to said site within the iframe, then it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

The script file can check if it is being executed in a top level window or not:

```
if( window.top != window.self)
    console.log("not inside top level windows")

if( window.top == window.self)
    console.log("inside top window");
```

and throw an error if executing in a top level window.

(Update) It could also specifically test for the being run inside an IFRAME element:

```
if( window.frameElement && window.frameElement.tagName == "IFRAME")
    console.log("this is definitely inside an IFRAME element");
```